# Press button fill textfield inside UIWebview For iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

i used normal code to link this url [Front Page URL](http://www.curhats.com/mobileapp/) and on pressing button "Mulai" Its not working but the second button works and loads another page.

Here is the code i used :

```
    _WebViewContent.delegate = self;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.curhats.com/mobileapp/"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_WebViewContent setScalesPageToFit:YES]; 
    [self.WebViewContent loadRequest:request];
```

The Button Mulai [This is mulai page](http://%22http://www.curhats.com/livechat/php/app.php?widget-mobile%22)

Please someone help me

Comment: Is there no error/debug log output? What exactly is "not working". Can you run it with a debugger?

Comment: In the webview i am not able to click the button "Mulai" as we see the same button in the url [link](http://www.curhats.com/mobileapp/)